# How to make Visual Studio working directory to be same as built executable's directory?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to understand how Visual Studio treats paths when they are being run from inside the IDE vs manually opening the executable file from bin. I have two projects that are linked together:

```
/demos
  /basic-triangle
    /src/...
/engine
  /src/...
/workspace
  /MyEngine.sln
  /engine
    /bin/Debug/assets
    /bin/Debug/engine.lib
    /engine.vcxproj
  /demos/basic-triangle
    /bin/Debug/basic-triangle.exe
    /basic-triangle.vcsproj
      -> references engine.vsxproj
```

So, in basic-triangle application, I have set up the following path:

```cpp
Engine::setAssetsPath(
        std::filesystem::path("../../../../engine/bin/Debug/assets").string());
```

This resolves to `/engine/bin/Debug/assets`, which looks like the path is counted from `bin` directory instead of `bin/Debug` directory. However, when I open the executable, the path is calculated from `bin/Debug`. How can I normalize this so Visual Studio uses the same current working directory as opening the executable file.

Comment: The working directory is configured in the project settings under "Debugging".

Comment: Perhaps use the ExecutablePath function.  It depends on what you mean to achieve as an end result?

Comment: @tkausl Is there any drawbacks to changing the working directory? I am asking this because changes to this file is saved in user settings instead of project settings.

Comment: @James I don't want to use ExecutablePath (at least not now) because it adds too much complexity since my application supports Linux, macOS, and Windows.

Comment: Just use Combine which should account for OS.

Comment: Just make a symbolic link instead in the command prompt.  It will be easier.  Use mklink /D <your target folder> <your source folder>